# matplotlib is not plotting any graph

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code of Bresenhem's line algorithm. I am trying to generate line using this. The graph terminal is displaying the graph but not any lines on it.

I tried to copy-paste code from the net and it displayed the graph successfully but my code is not generating the graph.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1,x2=[int(x) for x in input("Enter x1 and x2: ").split()]
print("x1 is {} and x2 is {}".format(x1,x2))
y1,y2=[int(x) for x in input("Enter y1 and y2: ").split()]
print("y1 is {} and y2 is {}".format(y1,y2))
dx=abs(x2-x1)
dy=abs(y2-y1) 

if dx>dy:
    l=dx
else:
    l=dy

dx=(x2-x1)/l
dy=(y2-y1)/l
x=round(x1+0.5*dx)
y=round(y1+0.5*dy)

i=1
while(i<=l):
    plt.plot(x,y)
    x=x+dx
    y=y+dx
    i=i+1

plt.show()
```

Comment: You are trying to plot a single data point as a line, which can't work. If you change `plt.plot(x,y)` to `plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')` [(stands for blue circle marks)](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) it will plot the points.

Comment: oh thanks a lot, it solved the problem